# Convert GeoJSON string to Elasticsearch Geometry

Tags: elasticsearch, geometry, geojson

I have a GeoJSON string like this

```
{
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  121.4,
                  33.99831528411953
                ],
                [
                  120.32770211588034,
                  33.09540949748297
                ],
                [
                  121.4,
                  32.20168471588049
                ],
                [
                  122.47229788411967,
                  33.09540949748297
                ],
                [
                  121.4,
                  33.99831528411953
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
```

I want transform it to Elasticsearch Geometry or ShapeBuilder.

But I didn't find a convenient way.

Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Or have tool classe can do this.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to parse this GeoJSON into a Geometry/Shapes? is that right?

Comment: Yes, and I am useing Elasticsearch 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution like

```
 String valueAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(value);

        GeometryParser parser = new GeometryParser(true, true, true);
        XContentParser contentParser = JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, DeprecationHandler.THROW_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, valueAsString);
        contentParser.nextToken();
        Geometry geometry = parser.parse(contentParser);
```

but I dont know this is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this:

```
// read your GeoJSON string from a file
String geojson = ...;

// parse the GeoJSON
JsonXContent geoJsonParser = JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, LoggingDeprecationHandler.INSTANCE, geojson);

// create a shape builder (of type PolygonBuilder since the GeoJSON represents a polygon)
PolygonBuilder shapeBuilder = (PolygonBuilder) ShapeBuilder.parse(geoJsonParser);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think it's the right way

Comment: It's not `ShapeBuilder.parse()` but rather `ShapeParser.parse()`, so it should be `PolygonBuilder shapeBuilder = (PolygonBuilder) ShapeParser.parse(geoJsonParser);`

Comment: Maybe you have to use `parser.nextToken();` in order to avoid an exception thrown by the ShapeParser, but I don't know why.